# Regular Expression for Find and Replace in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I want to remove leading and trailing tags from country names.
In my example those tags are `<li>` and `<a>`.

```
<li><a href="http://afghanistan.makaan.com/">Afghanistan</a></li>
<li><a href="http://albanie.makaan.com/">Albanie</a></li>
<li><a href="http://algérie.makaan.com/">Algérie</a></li>
```

Result should be:

```
Afghanistan
Albanie
Algérie
```

In Microsoft Word, I want to use the *Find and Replace* feature to accomplish it with regular expression.

How can I use regular expressions in MS Word?

Comment: your question is really not very clear. Are you saying you are starting with a word document and you want to use REG's to manipulate the text?

Comment: I want to create a database of Country names. So i copied(view source code) country names with leading and trailing <li> & <a> tags in this format :<li><a href="http://afghanistan.makaan.com/">Afghanistan</a></li>. Now i am looking for any technique to remove these leading and trailing tags from Country names. And i've choosen to accomplish it using ws-word's Find and Replace feature.

Comment: Define "database" - is your final output in word, or a 'real' database like postgres or mysql?

Comment: phatmanace,
Thanks for your response.
I want to use these country names in SQL Database and 
to create javaScript's country database(Afghanistan|Albanie|Algérie).

Comment: added another bit of my answer, given the latest information.

Comment: @user2791156 I did a major edit on your question. I hope I haven't misinterpreted anything. Also, is VBA a valid solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to search for a pattern in a MS Word document?](http://superuser.com/questions/846646/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-a-ms-word-document)

Comment: This question could be a lot better if it came up with something that actually requires regex. Removing tags `<li>` and `<a>` themselves would be easily doable with simple replace, unless you want to remove the hyperlink in the `href` part as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying your input text to Word, copy it to Notepad++ or any other editor with full RegEx support.

A RegEx string to select everything outside of tags or everything between `>` and `<` signs would be.

```
(?<=>).*?(?=<)
```

[image]

- `(?<=>)`  is a [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It looks for `>` signs and acts as an anchor. This way you can exclude the search string, which is important since you don't want `<Afghanistan`
- `.*?` is a [lazy quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Greedy) and selects everything until the very next expression
- `(?=<)`  is a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and looks for a `<` sign but excludes the searched sign itself. Just like the look behind

---

**But** you don't want to select the country names. You want to remove every tag. You need the opposite of the first regular expression. Somthing like

```
<.*?>
```

[image]

1. Open Notepad++ search & replace dialog
2. Select *Use regular expressions*
3. Find what: `<.*?>`
4. Replace with: nothing

Comment: nixda, You are brilliant. Solution worked for me. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do in MS Word's *Find and Replace*, without Regex, without JavaScript, etc.

If you escape a bracket it finds the actual bracket character. So, with wildcards toggled on, the expression `\<*\\>` will find everything between angle brackets. Just replace that with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx) looks like it's what you need.

Given latest comment (that you just want it in javsacript) - I'd look somewhere like [here](http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/option/world-countries.php)

if you want that in a SQL database, then I'd probably just write a couple of lines of perl to give you the list from the raw javascript. As far as I can tell; MS word doesn't come into it.

Comment: phatmanace, Thanks for your efforts made for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use find/replace for that.  It would be simplest to use "Text to Columns" in Excel for that task.  To do it, select the column that contains the text, go to the "Data" ribbon and select "Text to Columns".  You will need to do it twice, once to remove all the text prior to the country name (delimited symbol would be ">" - make sure you delete the extraneous columns to avoid confusion) and once to remove the text after the name (delimited symbol would be "<").