# Is there a way to search for a pattern in a MS Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

Is there a way to look up patterns inside an MS Word document instead of an exact match?

I have a document where all decimals have been written as `/` instead of `.`. For example, `1.02` has been written as `1/02`, because Persian typography uses `/` instead of `.` for the decimal point.

As `/` is not only used for decimals, and it has other applications, for example, fractions, percentage, etc., is there a way to find a pattern like `N/M` within a word document, where `N` denotes a decimal and `M` also shows another decimal number?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate more than 5 years after Super User launched?

Comment: A starting point may be *[Regular Expression for Find and Replace in Microsoft Word](http://superuser.com/questions/682345)*.

Comment: Well it would be hard to move it to notepad if there were other text in the middle, lets assume that one is writing a journal article(please use latex instead) so they cant move it out of word, or something of that nature, they would loose all the other formatting.

Comment: I've just verified: the latest MS Word versions store Word documents (*.docx) as zipped XML based documents. Once you know how this structure works, you might unzip your *.docx file and do a pattern match in the resulting XML files structures.

Comment: @Dominique that is interesting. Didn't know that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> like 'N/M' within a word document, where N denotes a decimal and M
>   also shows another decimal number

Just for a search you can use `^#/^#` as your search parameter. Under the **more** options, and **find Special**, there are some other options that can be helpfull.

Nb: `^#` , is one decimal place so if you are looking specifically for x/yy then it would be `^#/^#^#` etc.

to Replace,

This is a better option , perform search with `([0-9])/([0-9])` and replace with `\1.\2` , and enable "use wildcards"

Comment: Thanks. this finds the hits. but Word does not accept ^#.^# for the replacement part. I want to leave the digits surrounding '/' intact and replace '/' with '.'.

Comment: try doing a search with this, "([0-9])/([0-9])"  and replace with "\1.\2"  , take out the double quote. and enable "use wildcards"

Answer (score 51):

### Word

Use Microsoft's implementation of regular expressions

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> » click on ***More*** » Enable ***Use wildcards***

- Find what: `([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})`
- Replace with: `\1.\2`

[image]
[image]

This looks like a crazy search pattern so let's examine it:

- `[0-9]` stands for a single numeric value (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9)
- `{1,2}` is used for counting occurrences of the previous character or expression. In our case this means: *Search only for one or two numerics*.

  Caution: If you're using a german Word, you have to use `;` as separator instead of `,`
- `/` has no special meaning. It literally searches a slash
- `()` the round brackets are important. They divide the pattern into logical sequences so we can later use `\1`,`\2`...`\n` in our replace pattern. This way we preserve values

Read more on the section *[The expressions, Piece by piece](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f#__toc286834995)* in Microsoft's support article or on [Graham Mayor's Word site](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

---

### VBA (better solution)

I suggest you to use a VBA method which adheres more to the default from other RegEx engines. They are [better documented](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) and more people can help you.

This macro asks for a RegEx pattern to search in the whole document and replace it with your given string.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor. Paste the code anywhere and execute it with <kbd>F5</kbd>

```
Sub RegexReplace()
    
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")    
    On Error Resume Next

    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = InputBox("Find what:")
    ActiveDocument.Range = _ 
        RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, InputBox("Replace with:"))        
    
End Sub
```

- Find what: `(?!\d)/(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `.`

[image][image]