# How to use wildcards to find the years between 1900 and now

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards, syntax, range

I want to know the number of times that any year from 1900 through the current year is mentioned in a Word file.

I know how to use a wildcard expression to do this in two steps as follows:
<(19[0-9]{2})> to find matches 1900-1999
<(20[0-9]{2})> to find matches 2000-2099

What is the syntax to reduce this to one step?

In case it makes a difference, I am using Word 2010.

**Reason for Question**
When I estimate the effort to edit academic papers, I want to factor in the sheer number of in-text citations that need to be "eyeballed" for missing commas, parentheses, and such.

The sheer number needs to be one I have high confidence in; the number does not have to be exact.

Comment: Try `<([19|20][0-9]{2})>` Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Best you could do is look for 4 digit numbers starting with 1 or 2 <[1-2][0-9]{3}> but how accurate that is depends very much on the content of the document.

Comment: Peter, it picks up dates in the 1700s and 1800s.

Answer (score 0):

By studying the answers from der_michael (above) and Peter (below), I was able to combine their advice to arrive at this answer:

<[1920]{2}[0-9]{2}>

So far I've tried the syntax with three papers, with the number of in-text citations ranging from 300-731. The number of false positives were acceptable (1, 2, and 2).

Comment: `[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]>` is slightly better, but still not good since it matches `2999` too. Don't use `<`. Use a normal space instead. In my test file `<` also matches negative numbers like `-1999`. Word's wildcard search doesn't support OR-expression `|` which would solve the problem. Anyway, a VBA regex version is your best shot

Answer (score 0):

This is a Regular expression to match all years between 1900 and 2015

```
\s((19[0-9][0-9])|(200[0-9])|(201[0-5]))\s
```

- The basic structure is `((first_range) OR (second_range) OR (third_range))`
- We use a logical OR `|` to allow three ranges

  - `(19[0-9][0-9]` goes from 1900 - 1999
  - `(200[0-9])` goes from 2000 - 2009
  - `(201[0-5])` goes from 2010 - 2015
- `\s` looks for whitespace before and after a match. This prevents negative numbers

Unfortunately, you cannot use this pattern in Word's *Find & Replace* dialog. You have to open your VBA editor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and paste the below macro. Execute it with <kbd>F5</kbd>

An input window will pop up where you enter your RegEx pattern. The macro counts all occurrences and highlight them if you choose to

```vb
Sub RegexReplace()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'On Error Resume Next

    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = InputBox("Enter your regex pattern to find and count")
    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)

    answer = MsgBox("There are " & Matches.Count & " occurances" & vbCrLf & _
        "Highlight them?", vbYesNo)

    If answer = vbYes Then
        For Each hit In Matches
           ActiveDocument.Range(hit.FirstIndex, hit.FirstIndex + hit.Length). _
             HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Next hit
    End If

End Sub
```

### Result in Word

[image]

### Used resources

- http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm
- https://superuser.com/a/846681/50173
- http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/