# Removal of everything between two characters in Ms Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, regex

I need a pattern to remove everything between the "<" and ">" characters. An example would be:

`<blah blah blah>Something I want <blah blah>really bad<blah blah>`

becomes

`Something I want really bad`

How would I go about doing this? I have looked up the word search patterns and tried using them (to no avail). If Word won't do it, is there an online tool that could?

Comment: Obligatory reference to the famous bobince answer over at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [If you're interested in a notepad++ solution](http://superuser.com/a/683194/50173)

Comment: Why can't you just replace the < and > with [ and ]   ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I need a search pattern to remove everything between the "<" and ">" characters.

- Set "Find What" to `\<(*{1,})\>`
- Set "Replace with" to an empty string.
- Check "Use wildcard"

Notes:

- `<` and `>` are special characters that need to be escaped using `\`
- `*` means any character
- `{1,}` means one or more times

---

#### Further reading

- [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx)

Comment: Your code works for `<` and `>` but it doesn't seem to work with `[` and `]` When I use wildcard with this : `\[(*{1,})\]` word can't find anything but if I only look for `[` or `]` without wild card, all the `[` and `]` are found. Any idea why? ( I tried with and without the `\` to escape the `[` and `]` ). Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a different question to the OP. Please ask your own question and include examples of the text before and after you required changes.

Comment: Sorry for this, here is my question: http://superuser.com/questions/1011506/remove-of-everything-between-and-in-word-regex